# MongoDB aggregate, $addFields not working on $cond

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, pipeline

I've been using a Survey collection and $lookup to find associated answers to the survey questions.

Now I want to introduce a user_oid and create a "user_answer_count", using $addField.

**Code:**

```
Survey.aggregate([
    { $match: { team_oid: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.t_oid) } },
    { $addFields: { count_questions: { $size: "$questions"} } },
    { $unwind: { path: "$questions" } },


    { $lookup: { from: 'answers', localField: 'questions', foreignField: 'question_oid', as: 'answer' } },
    { $unwind: { path: "$answer", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    { $addFields: { 
        answer_count: { $cond: [{ $eq: [{ $type: "$answer" }, "object" ]}, 1, 0] } },
        user_answer_count: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$answer.user_oid", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.u_oid) ]}, 1, 0] }
    },


    { $lookup: { from: 'votes', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'surveyOid', as: 'votes' } },
    { $unwind: { path: "$votes", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    { $addFields: { vote_count: { $cond: [{ $eq: [{ $type: "$votes" }, "object"] }, 0.2, 0] } } },

    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        huddle_number: { $first: "$huddle_number" },
        count_questions: { $first: "$count_questions" },
        count_answers: { $sum: "$answer_count" },
        count_votes: { $sum: "$vote_count" },
        count_user_answers: { $sum: "$user_answer_count" },
        sefirot_state: { $first: "$sefirot_state" },
        created_date: { $first: "$created_date" },
        avg_positive: { $avg: "$answer.positive" },
        avg_creative: { $avg: "$answer.creative" },
        avg_focused: { $avg: "$answer.focused" },
        avg_friendly: { $avg: "$answer.friendly" },
        avg_aligned: { $avg: "$answer.aligned" },
        avg_alert: { $avg: "$answer.alert" }
      }
    }
]).exec((err, doc) => {
```

Everything here works, the first $addField "answer_count" works perfectly. But the second one, "user_answer_count" fails the whole thing.

Console says:  `Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators`

This is my first attempt at using $lookup with $addFields, so suggestions appreciated!

**Edit:**

Example Docs

```
**Survey**
_id : 5f5a372d9ea9981e7c5773cb
questions :
    0 : 5f522b025dd8993e58283522
    1 : 5f47a892db023557105e2be3
    2 : 5f522a9d5dd8993e58283520
    3 : 5f0e23ef2e0fcb3fe04a7314
    4 : 5f522b285dd8993e58283523
created_date : 2020-09-10T14:24:45.439+00:00
team_oid : 5f44cc20c74f8a444851d9c2
huddle_number : 22
sefirot_state : "Aligned"
__v : 0

**Answer**
_id : 5f58bb04772a5943a0b54ec9
question : "What does "winning" look like in this team?"
question_oid : 5f522bc55dd8993e58283526
user_team_oid : 5f44cc20c74f8a444851d9c2
user_oid : 5f1ef3e8accff82f3cae3957
comment : "It means Cobra Kai Never Die and Only Get Better"
created_date : 2020-09-09T11:22:44.098+00:00
__v : 0
```

Comment: Thanks @turivishal - I tried this, but got the same error...

Answer (score 1):

There are few fixes, missed brackets and `$cond` syntax not correct, also that way is wrong to get count of array.

- count number of element in array use `$size`, for `answer_count`
- you can use `$reduce` array operator for get count of count by user, no need to use `$unwind` answer array

```
  { $lookup: { ... } }, // skipping
  {
    $addFields: {
      answer_count: { $size: "$answer" },
      user_answer_count: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$answer",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: ["$$this.user_oid", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.u_oid)] },
              { $add: ["$$value", 1] },
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nCMsPB1QIWW)

Comment: Thanks @turivishal. This is a helpful answer and it works well, however it does not work when I apply to my code. I think because I am performing previous operations in the `aggregate` method, the data is already structured? I added the rest of the aggregation in my question, if you want to have a look. I am trying to solve it on my end. Thanks again, if I can make this work I will accept this answer.

Comment: Okay provide some documents for other collection also in playground, so i will look into it